# proof - if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2xyz$ then $x = y = z = 0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Well, I have been trying to prove that:

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2xyz \implies x = y = z = 0$$

and have made little progress. Till now, I have only been able to prove that if this is to happen then $x$, $y$ and $z$ must be even. I am explaining how I arrived to this result but don't know how to proceed further or even figuring this out would make sense.

If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2xyz$, then at least one of $x$, $y$ or $z$ must be a multiple of 2. Let that one number be x and now $2|x$. Also let $x = 2a$.Then, $4a^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4ayz$.

Now **assume that one of $y$ or $z$ is odd. So the other must be odd as well** as odd and odd add upto even and we need an even number to make the equality true. But it can be proved that **the sum of squares of two odd numbers is never a multiple of $4$**. Then the LHS would no longer be a multiple of 4 ($4a^2$ is a multiple of $4$ but $y^2 + z^2$ isn't) while the RHS would be. This is a contradition. Hence, $y$ and $z$ both are even. That's what I have been able to prove till now and still don't know if that is useful.

Please help if you have an answer.

Comment: What about $x=y=z=(3/2)$?

Comment: I think he might mean integers.

Comment: @Daron It's not stated explicitly in the question, but it's tagged under [tag:diophantine-equation], so I don't think that's a valid solution.

Comment: Have you tried applying AM-GM in a clever way?

Comment: @Daron Forget about the diophantine equation for a minute but how did you derive $3/2$? Was it some calculation or trial-and-error?

Comment: I set $x=y=z$ and then solved for the value of $x$. Then I plugged the three values back in to check they are indeed solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your proof that $x,y,z$ are all even is correct. You can use similar reasoning to continue.

Lemma $1$: If $x^2+y^2+z^2=2^n xyz$ for some $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$, $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, then $x,y,z$ are all even.

The proof is analogous. $x,y,z$ cannot all be odd (because the LHS would then be odd and the RHS even), so WLOG let $x=2x_1$.

The equation becomes $4x_1^2+y^2+z^2=2^{n+1}x_1yz$, so $4\mid y^2+z^2$, so $y,z$ are both even (you know how to prove it).

Lemma $2$: If $x^2+y^2+z^2=2^nxyz$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$, $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$, $z=2z_1$, then $x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2=2^{n+1}x_1y_1z_1$.

The proof is trivial. Lemma $1$ and $2$ together imply that if $x^2+y^2+z^2=2^nxyz$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$, then $x,y,z$ are divisible by arbitrarily large powers of $2$.

I.e., for all $k\in\mathbb Z^+$ we have $2^k\mid x,y,z$, which can only be possible if $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: By Lemma 1, you simplified that idea that all must be even to a great extent. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are close to an answer. Assuming $x = 2a, y = 2b, z = 2c$, we get
$$
4a^2 + 4b^2 + 4c^2 = 16abc\\
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 4abc
$$
Now apply the exact same reasoning to see that $a, b, c$ must all be even as well. And this carries on forever. Therefore $x, y, z$ must be infinitely divisible by $2$, and the only such number is $0$.

Comment: That was cool! So you prove it as there is no number infìnitely divisible by 2. This was a great idea. I didn't know you could use recursion like this.

Comment: @DhruvSomani It's more or less the same as the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational. You show that if there is a fraction $\frac pq = \sqrt 2$, then $p$ and $q$ are both infinitely divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Now I will prove another claim: There is no triple of positive integers that satisfy the equation.

Suppose there is. Take $2^k$ as the largest power of $2$ that divide $x,y$ and $z$ so that $x=2^k\alpha$ $y=2^k\beta$ and $z=2^k\delta$. Then LHS can  be written as $2^{2k}(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\delta^2)$. Now if you rewrite RHS as well and take out common factors

$$
\alpha^2+\beta^2+\delta^2=2^{k+1}\alpha\beta\delta
$$

where at least one of $\alpha,\beta,\delta$ is odd. The RHS in this new equation is even then this implies all at least two of $\alpha,\beta,\delta$ is odd. You can pick one even member say $\delta$ bu then $\alpha^2=\beta^2=1(mod4)$ and $\delta^2=0(mod4)$ but then $LHS=2(mod4)$ and $RHS=0(mod4)$. So this is obviously a contradiction.

Given this then at least one of $x,y,z$ should be zero, say $z=0$, but then this implies both $x=y=0$.

Comment: LHS can be written as.. Why $2^{2k}$ not $2^k$?

Comment: @DhruvSomani $\left(2^k\alpha\right)^2+\left(2^k\beta\right)^2+\left(2^k\delta\right)^2=2^{2k}\left(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\delta^2\right)$. What do you mean?